# Java Graphics Drawing

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Hello I'm making a tiled based game engine and  so far things have been going good with it, the only thing is I'm using JLabels to draw the tile graphics to the screen, is this a bad way of doing things or not? If so what better methods are there to use?

Comment: Well as much as it's easy to create a bunch of labels in rows and columns, it won't be easy to paint the moving Sprites over the JLabels, I would create a custom Swing component extending JComponent that takes in a 2D array or some data structure representing the world that then draws the tiles visible. There's more initial work in creating that custom component though, a good learning experience though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is somewhat vague and is open to interruption, which could lead to assumptions, however, we could look at the pros and cons of different choices...

## Using Labels

- Isolated, they manage the selves and are capable of displaying images without much work
- Can display animated GIFs without much work
- Are easily laid out into grid pattern
- Are difficult to apply special effects, especially effects that effect multiple cells
- Depending on the the complexity, it can use more resources

## Custom Painting

- Immediately increases the complexity as you not only become responsible for painting the component, but managing the individual states of the cells
- Animation becomes more complex, as you become response for managing the timings and updates
- Provides better support of layered effects, as you can apply the effects to the image and are not to the individual cells
- Resource management can be more complicated, but because you can control it, can provide better results in terms of resource usage...

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Answer (score -1):

JLabels work well and are easy to manage, but if you are making it in a applet you can use the  Java Graphics library and the paint method to draw objects in a more precise, linear way. Here is an example below

```
package packs;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class applet extends java.applet.Applet {


public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 200);
}
```

This draws a simple rectangle. Hope this helps!

Comment: You should be following the the [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), AWT is over 15 years out of date and was replaced with Swing. You should avoid painting to top level containers, and instead paint to component of some kind. You should be calling super.paint if nothing else. And don't get me started of the joys of applet development over desktop development

Comment: This is just another option.